# Laplace's Method modifications

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I was wondering if there is a "[Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method)" to estimate, as $n \to \infty$, integrals of type
$$ I_n = \int_0^\infty e^{nh(x)}g(nx) \, dx $$
where $g$ is a smooth function, that converges to a limit $L$ when $x \to \infty$.
Function $h$ achieves its maximum at some point $x_0 > 0$ and it is twice differentiable.

Alternatively, it would be useful for me a method for the integral
$$ I_n = \int_0^\infty e^{nh(x, n)} g(x) \, dx. $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The second form of the integral is probably the better place to start.  The approach will depend a lot on the function $h$.  Do you have a specific $h$ in mind?

Comment: You can think of $h(x, n)$ as something like the Gamma integrand $h(x,n) = \log(x) - \frac{x}{n}$. The change of variables $y = \frac{x}{n}$ transforms the problem to the first form.

Comment: In that case you're looking at $$\int_0^\infty e^{n\log x} e^{-x}g(x)\,dx,$$ and since the function in the exponent, $\log x$, doesn't have a maximum on $(0,\infty)$, the behavior of the integral will depend a lot on how the function $e^{-x}g(x)$ decays.  We still need more information to do the analysis.